# Cycles Bake Issues

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I've used Blender for several years now, but I haven't gone deep into anything. I'm looking at improving my current work and I've started using texture baking. So far I have a small understanding of it but I'm having an unusual issue with the bake results.

This is the original

[image: Forge]

[image: None Metallic]

This is the render view. I've built my materials and so on and, originally, I had metallic active. Because I have no idea how to use specular with Hl2's Engine I took it out and I'm using the reflective property.

[image: Low Quality / Pixelated]

The issue is that, no matter how I bake, cycles keeps doing this to all my diffuse, lightning or combine bakes. I've tried using a higher resolution image, adding environments, increasing samples to 800 from 138 default, remaking the materials, changed from 2.78, 2.79 and 2.80.

I've watched tutorials and look around and I seem to be doing everything right, the UV's are on 2048x2048 and are spread out.

[image: UVs]

But the result is always the same and it is stopping me from completing my work, because I cant seem to get a decent quality bake.